# Highcharts area spline values have incorrect position on y-axis

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I have an area spline highchart that seems to incorrectly place data points along the y-axis. I'm using the angular-highcharts directive and delivering the chart options through my service. The data itself is correct, as are the labels, the points are just placed too high along the y-axis. See image and code below:

[image: simple area spline]

Service function:

```
    function getReportingChart(quarterlyData, chartType, reportingType) {
        // extract top 4 drugs
        var top4 = _.sortBy(quarterlyData, 'x2q2').reverse().slice(0, 4);

        var dataSeries = [];
        var firstDrug = quarterlyData[0];
        var seriesNumber = 0;
        var quarters = ['Q1 2012', 'Q2 2012', 'Q3 2012', 'Q4 2012', 'Q1 2013', 'Q2 2013', 'Q3 2013', 'Q4 2013', 'Q1 2014', 'Q2 2014'];

        _.each(top4, function (drug) {
            var name = drug.A;
            var dataArray = [];

            dataArray.push(drug.x0q1);
            dataArray.push(drug.x0q2);
            dataArray.push(drug.x0q3);
            dataArray.push(drug.x0q4);
            dataArray.push(drug.x1q1);
            dataArray.push(drug.x1q2);
            dataArray.push(drug.x1q3);
            dataArray.push(drug.x1q4);
            dataArray.push(drug.x2q1);
            dataArray.push(drug.x2q2);

            var newDataSet = new buildSeries(name, dataArray, seriesNumber);
            dataSeries.push(newDataSet);
            console.log(newDataSet);

            seriesNumber += 1;
        });

        return {
            options: {
                chart: {
                    type: chartType
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        stacking: 'normal'
                    }
                },

            },
            series: dataSeries,
            title: {
                text: 'Top 4 Drugs By ' + annotateChartByType(reportingType).titleSuffix
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            loading: false,
            xAxis: {
                categories: quarters,
                tickmarkPlacement: 'between',
                labels: {},
                min: 0.5,
                max: quarters.length - 1.5,
                startOnTick: false,
                endOnTick: false
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: annotateChartByType(reportingType).yAxis.title
                },
                labels: {
                    format: annotateChartByType(reportingType).yAxis.unitformat
                }
            },
            size: {}
        };


    }
```

Below is the annotateChartByType function:

```
    function annotateChartByType(params){
        var defaultOption = {titleSuffix:" Primary Reports", yAxis: {title: "Number of Reports", unitformat: '{value}'}};

        switch (params) {
            case 'ps-cases':
                return defaultOption;
            case 'patients':
                return {titleSuffix:" Patient Incidence Rate",yAxis: {title: "Incidence Rate", unitformat: '{value:,.2f} %'}};
            case 'serious-outcomes':
                return {titleSuffix:" Outcome Rate", yAxis: {title: "Incidence Rate", unitformat: '{value:%.2f} %'}};
            case 'serious-adverse-events':
                return {titleSuffix:" Serious AE Rate", yAxis: {title: "Incidence Rate", unitformat: '{value:%.2f} %'}};
            default:
                return defaultOption;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity have you tried placing another data point past the one that is rendering incorrectly?  Does it only display wrong if it is the last data point?  I've recently been using AngularJS and Highcharts together and have had a few similar quirks.

Comment: I don't use Angular, so this maybe a dumb question.  But, what does annotateChartByType(reportingType).yAxis.unitformat look like?

Comment: @SmegheadSev all the points seem to be off by the same order of magnitude, not just the last point.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird, that is a custom function written to produce the values for the data labels (25 366 in this case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you have:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'normal'
    }
}
```

This means that the value you are seeing is indeed correct for the blue series, but it is stacked upon three other series, which makes it go higher on the y-axis. If this is unintentional just remove this code.

If it is intentional you can get the total instead of the series value using the `total` value in a `formatter` or `pointFormat`. See this `pointFormat` example:

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.total})<br/>'
}
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dLkgp6e5/). This is the default with the parenthesis added to show the total.